# Работая с React-thunk делают обычно отдельную папочку под thunks функции?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Работая с React-thunk делают обычно отдельную папочку под thunks функции или в store их пишут?

Comment: Одно из реализаций структуры thunk https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux

Comment: Автор говорит, что у него обычно 1-2 thunk, но у меня для одного reducer'a их 7 и они занимают 138 строчек кода